# How to write a regex which splits the string into an array when https and a trailing space are found in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with strings. The string often contains something like this:

"The site https://example.com contains all the information you need"

So far I have this regex, which splits the string when https? is found

```
const rgx_link = /(?=https?:\/\/)/gi;
```

So in this case it would split the string into:

```
arr = ["The site ", "https://example.com contains all the information you need"];
```

I would like to modify the regex, so it also splits the string if a space is found after the url.

The desired result would look like this:

```
arr = ["The site ", "https://example.com", " contains all the information you need"];
```

The new regex "should look" something like this `((?=https?:\/\/)(\s))`, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
const text = "The site https://example.com contains all the information you need";
const rgx_link = /(?=https?:\/\/)/gi;
const result = text.split(rgx_link);
console.log(result)
```

Edit 1: Wiktors suggestion is correct. Didn't notice that the leading part of the regex was changed, so it didn't work.

```js
const text = "The site https://example.com contains all the information you need";
const rgx_link = /(https?:\/\/\S*)/gi;
const result = text.split(rgx_link);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: let me ask, do you want to extract the URL(s) found in the string ?

Comment: no, I just want it to be split by https and if a trailing space is found. Sometimes its just "More info can be found on https://example.com" or "https://example.com has the information you need"

Comment: @DoomBot are you the OP ? If yes, please use the same account.

Comment: yea, I've been blocked, too many unanwsered questions... trying to get my rep up, so I can ask more.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this doesn't split it once it finds the space after https. I could modify the code so if `https` is found it splits that array entry on space, but I'd prefer to have a single regex that does the work.

Comment: You didn't implement Wiktor's suggestion correctly. Check again that regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
text.split(/(https?:\/\/\S*)/i)
```

Note that [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result) method outputs all captured substrings when the regex contains capturing groups, so this regex, being entirely wrapped with a capturing group, basically *tokenizes* the string into URLs and non-URL tokens.

Note the absence of the `g` flag, since `String#split` behavior by default is to split on all occurrences of the regex pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `http` - a `http` string
- `s?` - an optional `s` char
- `:\/\/` - a `://` substring
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
const text =
    "The site https://example.com contains all the information you need";
const rgx_link = /(?=https?:\/\/)/gi;
const result = text.split(rgx_link);

const url = result[1].split(" ")[0];
const rest = result[1].split(url + " ")[1];

const res = [result[0], url, rest];

console.log(res);
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Kind of. Thanks. Although I would like to have a regex which does this on its own

Answer (score 0):

in python I can search for an url then use the span position and use the end value to split the string after the url

```
data="""The site https://example.com contains all the information you need"""

def find_url(text):
    return re.search(r'https?://[^\s]*', text)

position=int(find_url(data).span()[1])

print(position)

print(data[0:position],data[position:-1])
```